# How to move the viewport in a bargraph for MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

Here is the code I used to make a barchart. I'm including it all in case there is an error here somewhere affecting the call to move the viewport as I can't the `moveViewToX()` method to work. The method `setVisibleXRange(4)` works and makes only 4 bars show. The graph then becomes scrollable but I cannot seem to get the `moveViewToX(2)` method to do anything.

```
BarChart barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.barchart);

ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
entries.add(new BarEntry(4f, 0));
entries.add(new BarEntry(8f, 1));
entries.add(new BarEntry(6f, 2));
entries.add(new BarEntry(12f, 3));
entries.add(new BarEntry(18f, 4));
entries.add(new BarEntry(9f, 5));

BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "# of fish");

ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
labels.add("05-Jan-2015");
labels.add("06-Jan-2015");
labels.add("07-Jan-2015");
labels.add("08-Jan-2015");
labels.add("09-Jan-2015");
labels.add("10-Jan-2015");

BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);

barChart.setData(data);
barChart.setDescription("# of fish in pond");
barChart.animateY(2000);

LimitLine line = new LimitLine(10f);
YAxis yAxis = barChart.getAxisLeft();

yAxis.addLimitLine(line);
yAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);

barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
barChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);

barChart.setVisibleXRange(4);
barChart.moveViewToX(2);
barChart.invalidate();
```